# Error facing while importing user from json file in keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to import users in keycloak through the below json file via Keycloak UI admin console:

```
[{
"Email":"abc@abc.com",
"Username":"abc@abc.com",
"FirstName":"ABC",
"LastName":"XYZ",
}]
```

but I am getting the error message as:
Error! Unable to parse JSON file.

Is there some issue with my json file?

Comment: have you solved this issue???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a trailing "," (comma) in your JSON.

```
[{
"Email":"abc@abc.com",
"Username":"abc@abc.com",
"FirstName":"ABC",
"LastName":"XYZ", <-- this is wrong
}]
```